# ssh include directive not working

Tags: ssh, openssh, sequelpro

So ssh works fine through console/terminal, but when I am using a MySQL database client (Sequel Pro), it seems to somehow be using a different ssh version, and the include directive therefore doesn't work. It states that it is using the proper SSH version, but does it switch at some point during the protocol?

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/devops
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/defaults
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/defaults line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/defaults line 76: Applying options for ch-pre-bastion
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/defaults line 80: Applying options for ch-pre-*
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Control socket " none" does not exist
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh gateway@52.33.83.63 -W 52.33.83.63:22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 502
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
/Users/me/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: include
/Users/me/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: include
/Users/me/.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably more SSH versions installed on your machine and the one from proxy command is probably picking up the old one, without `Include` support.

> debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh gateway@52.33.83.63 -W 52.33.83.63:22

Try to find a complete path to `ssh` binary and use it in the `~/.ssh/config` of `ProxyCommand` or just use `ProxyJump` option, which should choose correct `ssh` instance`.

Comment: I had to disable SIP on my mac and symlink the system version (usr/bin/ssh) (6.x) to my homebrew 7.5 version (usr/local/bin/ssh).